# How Can I check handset model using IMEI number in bulk?

Tags: web-services, api, imei

I need to find the handset model using IMEI number... There are some websites which provide this information for one or two IMEI in a day but I want some DB or webservice or API through which I can know the model of the phone using IMEI in bulk.. I have around 65000 IMEI number for which I want to know the model information and have to insert them in my DB.. Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a Type Allocation Code (TAC) reference.  The TAC is the first eight digits of the IMEI number and uniquely identifies the device.  The other digits are the serial number (and version and check digit info).

However, there is not a publicly available database of TAC codes.  New TAC codes come out almost daily, as new devices are registered and as new codes are issued for existing devices (for example, there are over 100 TAC codes for an especially popular device).  You can only get a complete list if you are affiliated with a wireless carrier or a manufacturer.  The codes are considered proprietary.